# Need Help Troubleshooting Custom Cartthrob Plugin

Tags: cartthrob, php, plugin

I have a custom plugin that was made by a previous developer. The client has asked for it to be modified to display all items ordered, instead of just one, and for some reason, the item name field is only displaying for the first result.

[image]

Here is the code. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking:

```
    class Purchased_items {
    
    public $return_data;
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->date_id_field = 'field_id_84';
    }
    
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    public function order_count()
    {
        $member = $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id');
        $count = 0;
        if($member)
        {
            $query = $this->EE->db->get_where("channel_titles", array("author_id" => $member, "channel_id" => 7, "status" => "complete"));
            $count = $query->num_rows();
        }
        return $count;
    }

    public function items()
    {
        $id = $this->EE->input->post('search:purchased_id');
        $start = $this->EE->input->post('start_on');
        $end = $this->EE->input->post('stop_before');

        $this->EE->db->save_queries = TRUE;
        $this->EE->db->from('cartthrob_order_items AS oi');
        $this->EE->db->join('channel_titles AS o', 'oi.order_id = o.entry_id', 'inner');
        $this->EE->db->join('channel_data AS od', 'o.entry_id = od.entry_id', 'inner');
        $this->EE->db->join('delivery_dates AS d', 'od.'.$this->date_id_field.' = d.date_id', 'left');
        $this->EE->db->select('oi.*, o.entry_date, d.date');
        if($id !=""){
            $this->EE->db->where(array('oi.entry_id' => $id, 'o.entry_date >=' => strtotime($start), 'o.entry_date <=' => strtotime($end), 'o.status' => 'complete'));
        }else{
            $this->EE->db->where(array('o.entry_date >=' => strtotime($start), 'o.entry_date <=' => strtotime($end), 'o.status' => 'complete'));
        }
        $query = $this->EE->db->get();

        // print_r($this->EE->db->last_query());
        // exit(print_r($query->result_array()));

        $dates = array();

        $item_options = array("default" => array("option_name" => "", "count" => 0, "total" => 0, "total_plus_tax" => 0, "day_totals" => array()));
        $date_counts = array();

        if($query->num_rows() == 0)
        {
            return $this->EE->TMPL->no_results();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach( $query->result_array() as $item )
            {
                $vars[0]["title"] = $item["title"];

                if( $item['extra'] != "" ){
                    $options = unserialize(base64_decode($item["extra"]));
                    $product_option = $options['product_options_other'];
                }
                if( $item['extra'] == "" || $product_option == "" ){
                    $name = "default";
                    $item_options[$name]["count"] += $item['quantity'];
                    $item_options[$name]["total"] += $item['price'];
                    $item_options[$name]["total_plus_tax"] += $item['price_plus_tax'];
                }
                else {
                    $extra = unserialize(base64_decode($item["extra"]));
                    $name = $extra['product_options_other'];
                    if( !isset($item_options[$name]) ){
                        $item_options[$name] = array("option_name" => $name, "count" => 0, "cost" => 0, "total" => 0, "total_plus_tax" => 0, "day_totals" => array());
                    }
                    $item_options[$name]["count"] += $item['quantity'];
                    $item_options[$name]["total"] += $item['price'];
                    $item_options[$name]["total_plus_tax"] += $item['price_plus_tax'];
                }
                if( !isset($item_options[$name]["dates"]) ){
                    $item_options[$name]["dates"] = array();
                }
                if( $item['date'] != "" ){
                    if( !isset($item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']] )){
                        $item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']] = array("date"=>$item['date'], "total_for_day" => 0);
                    }
                    $item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']]['total_for_day'] += $item['quantity'];
                }

            }
            // $vars = array("item_options" => array());
            if( $item_options["default"]["count"] == 0 ){
                unset($item_options["default"]);
            }
            foreach( $item_options as $option )
            {
                $option["day_totals"] = array_values($option["day_totals"]);
                $option["total"] = "$".number_format($option["total"], 2);
                $option["total_plus_tax"] = "$".number_format($option["total_plus_tax"], 2);
                $vars[0]['item_options'][] = $option;
            }
            return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$vars[0]["title"] = $item["title"];
```

Since that's inside a `foreach` loop, your resulting data is always limited to a single row (row "0").

Try this, starting at the appropriate matching spot:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
    return $this->EE->TMPL->no_results();
}
else
{
    $vars = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $query->result_array() as $item )
    {
        $vars[$i]["title"] = $item["title"];

        if( $item['extra'] != "" ){
            $options = unserialize(base64_decode($item["extra"]));
            $product_option = $options['product_options_other'];
        }
        if( $item['extra'] == "" || $product_option == "" ){
            $name = "default";
            $item_options[$name]["count"] += $item['quantity'];
            $item_options[$name]["total"] += $item['price'];
            $item_options[$name]["total_plus_tax"] += $item['price_plus_tax'];
        }
        else {
            $extra = unserialize(base64_decode($item["extra"]));
            $name = $extra['product_options_other'];
            if( !isset($item_options[$name]) ){
                $item_options[$name] = array("option_name" => $name, "count" => 0, "cost" => 0, "total" => 0, "total_plus_tax" => 0, "day_totals" => array());
            }
            $item_options[$name]["count"] += $item['quantity'];
            $item_options[$name]["total"] += $item['price'];
            $item_options[$name]["total_plus_tax"] += $item['price_plus_tax'];
        }
        if( !isset($item_options[$name]["dates"]) ){
            $item_options[$name]["dates"] = array();
        }
        if( $item['date'] != "" ){
            if( !isset($item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']] )){
                $item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']] = array("date"=>$item['date'], "total_for_day" => 0);
            }
            $item_options[$name]['day_totals'][$item['date']]['total_for_day'] += $item['quantity'];
        }

        if( $item_options["default"]["count"] == 0 ){
            unset($item_options["default"]);
        }
        foreach( $item_options as $option )
        {
            $option["day_totals"] = array_values($option["day_totals"]);
            $option["total"] = "$".number_format($option["total"], 2);
            $option["total_plus_tax"] = "$".number_format($option["total_plus_tax"], 2);
            $vars[$i]['item_options'][] = $option;
        }
        $i++;
    }   
    return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
}
```

Comment: As always, Derek, you are the best! Thank you!